# download doc file from django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to Django and im trying to download a string in doc/txt/csv file format.

I am not able to find the logic how to do this.

Django temple has a big string of data and i want to download it on click..

Thanks..

Comment: You need to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to output a CSV doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

I wanted to Output excel with Django and [here](http://reliablybroken.com/b/2009/09/outputting-excel-with-django/) is how we do it.